# Is it possible to build WebKit under Visual Studio and in Silverlight platform envi?

Tags: silverlight, webkit, webkit.net

Here, http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingOnWindows is said that I can use Visual Studio as building platform for WebKit (with cygwin). But I have poor english, so for a moment I didn't get yet all info that there was said. SO, my question for a poor knower of English: is it possible to Set All This Building For silverlight. Especially, me interested in WebKit.Interop.Dll as I trying to integrate WebKitDotNet in Silverlight app'lication. So, please don't be very strict (severe), with me. (I will read all remaining stuff on page of webkit.org after some realizing, for sure)

Answer (score 0):

To use native libraries (via Interop layer) from Silverlight you have to run as a trusted application and outside of the browser (OOB). Silverlight 5 allows trusted apps to also run in the browser but admin has to configure the machine first to allow this.

If you use OOB you can use WebBrowser control, so no real need for WebKit then
For inside the browser there are some free (and some commercial) HtmlBrowser controls that use a trick where Silverlight is set to run windowless (this has performance implications) and then they put a floating DIV above it at the correct place in the view to seem it is inside Silverlight (they also clip it appropriately so that it works with scrollpanes in Silverlight).